# OSX and others apps get really slow when it's running my GLFW project

Tags: xcode, macos, performance, glfw, slowdown

I thought that my computer was getting slow cause of the loop in the glfw loop:

```
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    ...
}
```

But when I run it the CPU usage displayed in XCode is just 15%. I wonder what may causing this whole slowing down situation in my system when I run (debug) my project.

I don't think that is this loop, cause I ran a silly code in another project:

```
while(1){
     printf("blah\n");
}
```

...And a loop that didn't broke yet, obviously, doesn't mean that the system is putting all the CPU effort on that. So, I wonder why this specific project is slowing everything down.

My code is on [Git](https://github.com/eduardo4jesus/OpenGLSL-GLFW/tree/master/OPENGLSL%20GLFW)

Comment: At a guess, I suspect that GLFW is forcing the window server to synchronize or lock its framebuffer. You can try sampling a process that seems to be running slowly.

Comment: Do you have any other tip about how to do this sampling on OSX?

Comment: Select a process in Activity Monitor and select Sample Process from the View menu. Or, use the [`sample`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sample.1.html) command. You can also use Instruments with the Time Profiler and other instruments.

Comment: Ok, I've got a huge plaintext. Is something special in it that a should be looking for?

Comment: I just commented the lines I create and draw my scene object so that I just have a blank screen. It seems normal. The fps is still the same as when I was drawing the object (around 16.67). On XCode debugger the CPU usage is even higher (around 33%), but the usage of XCode and other apps when XCode runs my code is not being perceptively affected.

Comment: in both cases (drawing my scene object or not) XCode debugger says that my executable have a very high energy impact. And after a while the fan start to speed up...

Comment: If you sample one of the other processes – one which is slowed down by your app – then you might find what it's spending its time waiting for. You would want to sample it while you're trying to use it and it's responding sluggishly. My guess is that you'll find that it's waiting on the window server. You could edit your question to include the sample report (possibly omitting the list of binary images, to keep it short).